# d3 Date Axis "Rounding"

Tags: d3.js

I'm attempting to have an X-Axis with dates. Unfortunately my data can be have a small range resulting in a date showing multiple times as an xTick. Is there a way to force it to only show "each date" exactly once as a tick.

For example, I don't want to see 12/29/2020 as a tick more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your version of d3, but `d3.timeDay` might be [what you need](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#time_ticks).

```js
var input = [new Date(1999, 11, 31, 0),new Date(2000, 0, 1, 0), new Date(2000, 0, 1, 2), new Date(2000, 0, 1, 3), new Date(2000, 0, 2, 2), new Date(2000, 0, 2, 5)];
console.log(input);

var x = d3.scaleTime().domain(input);

var xTick = x.ticks(d3.timeDay.every(1));
console.log(xTick)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks this solved it for me!